# How to have a checkbox remain highlighted on a responsive page from desktop to tablet view to mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a checkbox that when i click on it,it changes in color as follows:

```css
.checkmark {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 22px;
    /*height: 22px;*/
    height:17px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    margin-left:50%;
    margin-bottom:1px;
}
    .checkmark:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 3px;
        height: 9px;
        background-color: #ccc;
        left: 11px;
        top: 6px;
    }

.checkmark {
    cursor: pointer;
}

    .checkmark:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 3px;
        height: 3px;
        background-color: #ccc;
        left: 8px;
        top: 12px;
    }

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .checkmark:before,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .checkmark:after {
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(42, 104, 149) 0px, rgb(44, 109, 157) 100%);
}
```

```html
<label style="display: inline;color: #545454;font-weight:100;"    dataid="' +this.ID +'"  data-nodeid = "' +this.NodeId +'"><input type= "checkbox" style= "display:none;" id="cb' + this.ID + '">MILK
<span for="cb' + this.ID +'" class="checkmark"></span >
 </label >
```

The above works correctly.However when the page gets responsive,when i go from desktop to tablet view or mobile view the tick is no longer highlighted.For example if i click it on tablet view it will get highlighted and then when i make the screen smaller to the mobile site the tick loses its highlight.But if i click it again then the highlight will remain.How can i accomplish having the highlight remain in different responsiveness.
I tried the follwing

```
function check() {
            $("input:checkbox").on('change',function () {
                // var $checkmark = $(this);
                $('input[id="' + this.id + '"]:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);

            }); 
        }
```

the above passes multiple IDs instead of just one ID at a time.Is there anyway i can assign the highlight in a different way?

Comment: I don't really see the problem even when resizing it stays checked and highlighted.

Comment: works here,but not on my local site.not sure if maybe when its clicked i can add a highlight class or something?

Comment: Ofcourse you can add/ remove class on click

Comment: yeah,thats the part im confused about because i already added the class=checkmark

Comment: Just to let you know that it is possible to make the checkbox you want without JS just pure simple CSS. That way you also don't really need extra classes just rely on the pseudo classes.

Comment: i did create the checkbox with css,the part im stuck on is how to have the check remain checked once its clicked,so i was trying different scenarios

Comment: When you say in different views, did you say to select on the desktop and then go to the tablet (physical) and the checkbox is selected or is it just in terms of responsiveness? if it is the second question, as @SuperDJ it says, I do not see any problem.